# Unable to click "Yes" button using cypress.io

Tags: cypress

Using Cypress, I want to automate clicking a "Yes" button in a confirmation dialogue box "Yes".

I want to:

1. Check the button changes color when you hover over the mouse button;
2. When you click the "Yes" button, check for another confirmation box.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some of your code and as well some images that we see how far you are already.

Comment: it('Verify login Succesffully', function()
   {
      cy.get('#inputEmail').type("test@demo.com")
      cy.get('#inputPassword').type("test")
      cy.get('#kt_login_signin_submit').click()
    })

Answer (score 0):

1. Cypress doesn't support the hover effect as of now https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/hover.html#Workarounds
2. You can perform a `cy.contains('Yes').click()` followed by a `cy.contains('Confirmation message');` to first press on the yes button then check for a confirmation message.